# If exception occurs is there any way to send message into dead letter topic using c#?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have azure function app which trigger based on new message into service bus topic. `maxdeliverycount=10`

But if any exception occurs i want to send message into dead letter topic how to do that?

```
 [FunctionName("ProcessData")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "sub1", Connection = "ConnectionStringSettingName")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
        {           
            try
            {
                //process message mySbMsg
                DataSchema data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSchema>(mySbMsg);
                ...
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
              // How to send message into Dead letter explicitly ?
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are dead letter queues to which the message will be added if the processing of the message fails for configured number of times.

Comment: i want to send it explicitly because i have try catch block

Comment: Normally the message processing code removes the message from queue after successful processing. If processing is not successful the message remains in the queue and available for processing again. If there is any dead letter queue configured the message will be added to DLQ automatically after it is received configured number of times but not removed from the queue. So in your case you can have that configuration number set as 1 so that when there is an exception it will go to DLQ. You need to make sure that the message is removed from main queue after successful process

Comment: you are right but i have handle the exception not throw them , if we throw it then what you are saying that will happen...

Comment: @Neo You should use a trigger binding parameters such as  *MessageReceiver messageReceiver* and *string lockToken* to allow explicitly sending a message to the DLQ, for instance: *await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);*

Comment: yea thats the one i want to see the code snippet , could you please add an answer here it will be great help.

Comment: or only solution is add code `throw new Exception();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet shows an example of the MessageReceiver usage:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class Function8
{
    [FunctionName("Function8")]
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic2", "test2", Connection = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString")]
        string mySbMsg, string lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
            // await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, this solution uses the latest azure servicebus sdk, could you add some details around the nuget dependencies because it won't work with the old sdk ?

Comment: ok great thanks :) will it also do default retry for Max Delivery Count ?